# incorrect output of merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge

I am trying to write a merge sort algorithm using template functions in c++. The output is close but not correct. When I give the function the array [7, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 3], it returns [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 8]. I specifically believe that the problem is in the merge function rather than the merge sort function. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
template <class T1>
void mergeSort(T1 array[], int lower, int upper)
{
    if (lower < upper)
    {
        int middle = (lower + upper) / 2;

        mergeSort(array, lower, middle);
        mergeSort(array, middle + 1, upper);
        merge(array, lower, middle, upper);
    }
}

template <class T1>
void merge(T1 array1[], int lower, int middle, int upper)
{
    int i = 0,
        j = 0,
        k = 0;
    int size1 = middle - lower + 1;
    int size2 = upper - middle;
    T1* temp1 = new T1[size1];
    T1* temp2 = new T1[size2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        temp1[i] = array1[lower + i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
    {
        temp2[j] = array1[middle + 1 + j];
    }

    while (i < size1 && j < size2)
    {
        if (temp1[i] < temp2[j])
        {
            array1[k] = temp1[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            array1[k] = temp2[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    if (i == size1)
    {
        while (j < size2)
        {
            array1[k] = temp2[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (i < size1)
        {
            array1[k] = temp1[i];
            k++;
            i++;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
     int a[] = { 7, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 3 };
     mergeSort(a, 0, 6);
}
```

Output:

```
1 1 2 2 3 3 8
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: How is your output incorrect? Is it giving you a non-sorted result? Is it giving giving you a sorted result, but is not performing the merge-sort correctly? Posting an output example in your question would be helpful.

Comment: You seem to be missing `delete[] temp1;` and `delete[] temp2;`, don't you?  Not that it will affect the result, but don't forget to release what you allocate.

Comment: The array that I am putting into the mergeSort function is: int a[] = { 7, 6, 4, 8, 1, 2, 3 }; when I print the array again after running the function it prints: 1 1 2 2 3 3 8

Comment: What does the call to `mergeSort` look like?  Do you specify 7 or 6 for the upper bound?

Comment: I am calling the mergeSort function as follows: mergeSort(a, 0, 6);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `merge` function you shouldn't initialize `k` to 0 because it will write the result of merge in the wrong place. Instead you should initialize `k` to `lower`. Because that is the start index of the part you are actually sorting.

Comment: Thank you very much, seems obvious to me now!